# I am having trouble solving $T(n) = T(n/2) + n^2$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am working with the equation

$T(n) = T(n/2) + n^2$,
given $T(1) = 0$.

I started by using backwards substitution arriving at

$T( ( ( n - 1 ) / 2 ) + ( n - 1 ) ^ 2 ) + n ^ 2$
and eventually arrived at

$T( ( n - k ) / 2 )$ + the summation of $(n-i)^2$ from $i = 0...k$.
However, I am not sure where to go from here because using $T(1) = 0$ would give $0/2$ plus the summation which gives $0$.

This does not seem like it would work for $n = 1$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: assume you can write $n = 2^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  Then $T(n) = T(2^{k-1}) + n^2$.Then you'll eventually get $T(1)$ at the end and a sum of terms of the form $(n-i)^2$, which should be easy.

Comment: For later use, the general case is covered here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $n = 2^k$, $t(k) = T(2^k)$:

$\begin{align}
t(k) = t(k - 1) + 2^{2 k}
\end{align}$

This linear recurrence is easy to solve (or just write it as $t(k) - t(k - 1) = 2^{2 k}$ and sum over $k$).

Comment: How about the n which are not powers of 2?

Comment: This was my doubt too. My CS teacher does not address this point but it bothers me how a relation on natural numbers is generalised to irrational numbers like log n.

Comment: The above gives values for powers of 2. As written, the recurrence makes no sense otherwise. If you really mean $T(\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor)$, you see that the value obtained the way described gives a bound on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let n=$2^k$ for some k. Then we have
$$T(2^k)=T(2^{k-1})+2^{2k}$$
$$\Rightarrow T(2^k)=T(2^{k-2})+2^{2(k-1)}+2^{2k}$$
$$\Rightarrow T(2^k)=T(2^{k-3})+2^{2(k-2)}+2^{2(k-1)}+2^{2k}$$
and so on till we get
$$T(2^k)=T(2^0)+2^{2(k-(k-1))}+...+2^{2(k-2)}+2^{2(k-1)}+2^{2k}$$
$$\Rightarrow T(2^k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^{2(k-i)}$$ 
$$\Rightarrow T(2^k)=4\cdot\frac{4^{k}-1}{3}$$

Substituting the value of $2^k=n$ we get
$$T(n)=\frac 43\cdot (n^2-1)$$

Comment: If you set $S(n) = \frac{1}{2}n^2 - 2$, check whether $S(n) = S(n/2) + n^2$

Comment: Your first $2^{4k}$ should be $(2^k)^2 = 2^{2k} = 4^k$

Comment: Thank you. That was a silly mistake. I corrected it now.

Comment: I don't see the $n = 2^k$. How do you get that substitution?

Comment: I am mainly taking it because the height of the recursive tree will be an integer.